# Rotate uiscrollview when changed device orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios4, label, scrollview

please suggest me, is this a good to redraw `scrollview` with elements again and again instead of just rotating somehow all `view`, like default under iOS 6. And my app supports iOS > 4.3 .
  There are methods, that rotates `scrollview` and draw elements on this.

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didRotate:) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification"  object:nil];
    UIDeviceOrientation newOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    [self didRotate:newOrientation];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)didRotate:(UIDeviceOrientation)orientation {
    UIDeviceOrientation newOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

CGRect frame = CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.origin.x, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.origin.y, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width);
CGSize maximumSize;

if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(newOrientation)) {
    maximumSize = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
} else {
    maximumSize = CGSizeMake(frame.size.height, frame.size.width);
}

//self.scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.scrollView removeFromSuperview];
    [name removeFromSuperview];
    [text removeFromSuperview];
     self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, maximumSize.width, maximumSize.height)];

self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
name = [self configureLabel:name WithCoordsOfX:100.0f y:10.0f Width:self.scrollView.bounds.size.width Height:10.0f forKey:@"title"];
text = [self configureLabel:text WithCoordsOfX:10.0f y:110.0f Width:self.scrollView.bounds.size.width-20 Height:self.scrollView.bounds.size.height forKey:@"text"];
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.bounds.size.width, text.frame.size.height+220);
text.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];


// add myLabel
[self.scrollView addSubview:photo];
[self.scrollView addSubview:name];
[self.scrollView addSubview:text];
[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
NSLog(@"%f %f",self.scrollView.bounds.size.height,self.scrollView.bounds.size.width);
}
```

and

```
- (UILabel *)configureLabel:(UILabel *)label WithCoordsOfX:(float)x y:(float)y Width:(float)width Height:(float)height forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
    label.text = [personData valueForKey:key];
    [label setNumberOfLines:0];
    [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:14.0]];
    [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [label sizeToFit];

    return label;
}
```

I try to use this line of code, but it don't help me.

```
self.scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Also others views rotate cool just after

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;  
}
```

Please told me if there are "good" ways to change orientation of `UIScrollView`, or redraw elements is the best choice ? And any examples of that would be very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, method you are following will cause performance issue. You are not `redrawing` but `recreating` the subviews. It is not good programming to recreate the entire subview hierarchy just to have them in different sizes.

Ideally on device rotation, only change the frame of scrollview and subviews according to orientation. One way to deal with this is subclass `UIScrollView`, and override `layoutSubview` method in which you can relayout (change frame only and not recreate) subviews. Other wise you can enumerate the `UIScrollView` subviews in the `didRotate:` method and reframe them according to specific orientation.

Comment: Amar,Thank You for your answer! unfortunately, i don't completely understand how to work with layoutSubview with subclass of UIScrolView and following your answer, instead of init i'm make cgrectmake for uiscrollview and labels, so now i needn't to removeFromSuperview and added this scrollView to view. Otherwise i don't change didRotate:,but code became smaller and all works fine.Thank you!!!

Comment: In my case it's worked fine after I added:
`- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;//(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}` 
**and also:** `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    myScroll.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
}`